# Component within Component in hibernate mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Can we use component inside component in hibernate mapping file?

Comment: Can you pls more elaborate your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a one-to-one, one-to-many, or many-to-many relationship between two objects?  Of course you can:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html

Comment: I don't think that's what he meant

Comment: i meant component tag withing component tag. I found it working last night. Thanks.